# Xamarin ios unified version is not allowed to install Mvvmcross

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have updated xamarin ios from classic api to unified api.
When i trying to add Mvvmcross nuget package it shows following error

**Could not install package 'MvvmCross.PortableSupport 3.2.2'. You are trying to install 
this package into a project that targets 'Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0', but the package does 
not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that 
framework. For more information, contact the package author.**

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The MvvmCross.PortableSupport 3.2.2 NuGet package contains an empty Portable Class Library folder and can be installed into a Xamarin.iOS project if you have the Portable Class Libraries installed for Xamarin and if you have the latest version of NuGet installed.

So you may not have the PCLs installed for Xamarin or, if you are using Visual Studio, then your NuGet version may be too old and need to be updated.

**To get the Portable Class Libraries:**

If you are on the Mac you should install the [Mono Development Kit](http://www.mono-project.com/download/) (MDK).

If you are on Windows then things are can be more complicated. The simplest way is to install Visual Studio 2013 (full or Express) Update 2 or higher. The more complicated way is to install the [Portable Library Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b0e0b5e9-e138-410b-ad10-00cb3caf4981/) and the [Portable Library Reference Assemblies 4.6](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40727). The Portable Library Reference assemblies installs a PortableReferenceAssemblies.zip file which contains three directories (4.0, 4.5 and 4.6). These three directories need to be extracted and copied into the PCLs directory:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable
```

Finally on Windows you would then need to reinstall Xamarin. The easiest way to do this is to find Xamarin in the Control panel's Programs and Features and select the option to Repair it.